# Magento checkout cart feature control

Tags: magento, checkout, cart

I have a site, 1.5 magento, and the cart functionality (and the customer account functionality) seem to be disabled. When i attempt to go to the url 'checkout/cart', just the homepage displays.

Ive checked all the usual suspects..including:

- checked the url_rewrites table (there is one entry in their referencing checkout/cart...but goes from checkout/cart to checkout/cart, so dont see this is an issue, but did edit it just to rule it out)
- enabling/disabling of the module itself, looking at both the etc/modules files and removing, and checking the module listing in system->config->advanced area.
- trying to step through the code..try detect where the change over of pagedata occurs - struggling here.
- looking for certain terms in the codebase...and database SQL file.
- the htaccess file, looking for a rewrite
- local/community modules..and any rewriting of the checkout

Im starting to think a hack is in place here to show the homepage when visiting checkout url. The url : www.mysite.co.uk/checkout/cart remains in the address bar, but i see homepage data.

Anyone know where else i can check...or easily locate the cause of this issue?
Many thanks
S

Comment: customer and cart modules can't be disabled, without them magento will not work.. have you deleted your cache btw? have you tried in another browser?

Comment: Hi.   Yes and yes.
Ive just tried changing the template...a clean base, and the modern theme. It STILL displayed the homepage.

Thinking this must be database related now. Going to export and clear the rewrites at the minute...

Comment: Cleared the rewrites table....can access cart! Dammit...it was in their all along. Ill find the record....

Answer (score 1):

Did you look in backend under Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout ?

There is a field called "Enable One-Page Checkout" which has to be enabled. If you disable it, your store will just run fine but neither registered customers nor guests can check out anymore.

Comment: yes, thx, i checked those settings. Seems a rewrite was placed in the db...by hand i think.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was rewrites added to the rewrite table manually. Didnt find them at first.